# existence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Do there exist continuous functions $P$ and $Q$ on $[0,1]$ such that $y(t)=\sin\left(t^2\right)$ is a solution to $y''+Py'+Qy=0$ on $\big[\frac{1}{n},1\big]$ for all $n\geq 1$? Justify your answer.

Since $\frac{1}{n}\leq t \leq 1$; so as $n\to \infty$, $t\to 0$.  Now clearly if we put $y(t)=\sin(t^2)$ in the given differential equation, and take limit as $t\to 0$, we see that the given expression $y''+Py'+Qy$ tends to $0$,which satisfies our required criteria. So there are infinitely many solutions for $P$ and $Q$. Now is my logic true or not? Please justify this method, and provide any method if it's not legit.

Comment: What do you mean when you write that “the given differential equation tends to $0$”?

Comment: Why not just say $(0,1]$ instead of the $[1/n,1]$ business?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, sorry for that. Edited..

Comment: @zhw, because I wrote the problem exactly in the form as it was represented to me.

Comment: Fine, but remember you are also able to think for yourself. I don't see the point of these intervals $[1/n,1].$ Do you?

Comment: Definitely not, but is the solution hidden underneath that point of view?

Comment: I don't think so. Let me ask you this: What did you get for the expression $y''+Py'+ Qy$ with $y(t)=\sin(t^2)?$

Comment: Oh wait..it tends to $2$, not zero..then it's a contradiction if we assume existence of such functions, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I got.